# Underlining and underscores in Unicode-aware editors

Tags: printing, fonts, gedit, unicode

Here at home I use the Unity-based Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with `gEdit` and a Mate-equipped Slackware PC with `Pluma`.

I have always wanted to emulate the good old typewriter under Linux, so as not to be forced to use word processors. Editors were once unable to render *real* underlining of portions of text, but that is solved nowadays with UTF, Unicode and combining marks. Both `gEdit` and its fork `Pluma` can handle Unicode quite well and I am using them for all my writing needs.

To the best of my knowledge Unicode combining marks should be added *after* the letter they modify (see: tinyurl.com/zxo2a3k) but I have noticed that when I underline a block of text in Ubuntu/gedit its layout can be disrupted if I change the screen font. So it happens that I must set the same (monospaced) font to all editors in both PCs, which seems to me quite annoying as we are just talking about text files, after all. Or I must insert the combining underscore u+332 *before* the letter, depending on the font and whether I'm using `gEdit` or `Pluma`.

What happens is that if I underline a block of text in - say - Ubuntu Mono 13 and then I open that file in `Pluma` with a different screen font, or even if I change the font within the same editor, all the underscores get displaced by one character. And If I try to print to PDF or to a real printer the file, broken underlining stays there.

[image: Lorem Ipsum in Gedit, Ubuntu Mono 13]

[image: Lorem Ipsum in Pluma, Monospace 12]

Is this a bug or the consequence of different handling of UTF by different font types? Is there a way to make underlining independent of the screen font used across editors and machines?

Comment: This isn't probably worth an answer, but you change the compatibility of a document respectively with `sed -i 's/\xcc\xb2\(.\)/\1\xcc\xb2/g`(Gedit -> Pluma) and `sed -i 's/\(.\)\xcc\xb2/\xcc\xb2\1/g' file` (Pluma -> Gedit) (both untested, try with `-i.bak` in case I missed something).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On my part I have been thinking about this issue and searching the internet a bit after I posted my question. So I must add the U+332 underscore after the letter both in `gEdit` and `Pluma` with Ubuntu Mono and Free Mono; and I must add it before if I use Monospace or DejaVu. If I write in Ubuntu Mono and I open the file in Monospace, underscores are displaced by one space; and if I write in Monospace and I open the file in Ubuntu Mono, underscores are displaced by one space backwards.  It seems it's not really a matter of editors but rather of fonts and how they behave

Comment: Yeah I agree, overall this seems to be just about the font rendering.